# Al modificar datos desde NetBeans no se reflejan en la bbdd

Tags: java, mysql

Necesito Modificar datos a mysql desde NetBeans el problema es que cuando quiero modificar no se actualizan los datos en la bbdd

"Este es mi método para Modificar"

```
public boolean Modificar(Estudiante E, String rut, String nombre, float promedio){
        try {
            PreparedStatement ps;

            ps = objConn.getConn().prepareStatement(sql_update);
            ps.setString(1, E.getNombre());
            ps.setFloat(2, E.getPromedio());
            ps.setString(3,E.getRut());

            if(ps.executeUpdate() > 0){
                return true;
            }
        }  catch (SQLException ex){
            Logger.getLogger(DAOEstudiante.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }


        return false;
    }
```

"Este es el Main en el cual ingreso los datos"

```
            case 2:
                    System.out.println("+----------------------+");
                    System.out.println("| Modificar Estudiante |");
                    System.out.println("+----------------------+");
                    System.out.println("ingrese el RUT del Estudiante a modificar: ");
                    e1.setRut(in.next());
                    System.out.println("Ingrese el Rut del nuevo Estudiante");
                    e1.setRut(in.next());
                    System.out.println("ingrese el Nombre del nuevo Estudiante: ");
                    e1.setNombre(in.next()); 
                    System.out.println("ingrese el Promedio del nuevo Estudiante: ");
                    e1.setPromedio(in.nextFloat());
                    nuevo.Modificar(e1, rut, nombre, promedio);


                    break;
```

Comment: ponga el  método donde esta haciendo la conexión

Comment: El método modificar te devuelve algún error?

Comment: Además puedes poner la query que estás pasando?

Comment: @RichardVíquezPérez     private Conexion(){
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/curso?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull","root","");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
       
    }

Comment: Me parece que eso es un constructor de una clase ???  En caso de que sea un constructor lo que tiene que hacer es poner ese código en un método de esa clase y llamar ese método antes de hacer el update

Comment: En caso de que sea un método de igual forma debe llamarlo antes de hacer el update para abrir la conexión y también no olvide cerrar esa conexión.

Comment: Y revise que no este cayendo en ninguna excepción y si es así muéstrenos lo que dice la excepción

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar los atributos de la clase Estudiante e indicar cual es la clave primaria ?